# If 3 is a crowd... what about 8?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

*I have many children yet some would doubt that I love them.*

My first might have impressed if not for a knife.
My second's fall was far from bright.

My third kept undesirable company or drank too much wine,
While my fourth was abandoned, frozen in time.

My fifth liked his eels chopped and axed,
And my sixth preferred cooked, if anyone asked.

My seventh could not stand the sight of a bath,
While my last might have been first, but surely was there last.

*Name me and my children.*

**Hint #1** (children described in clues above are numbered 1 to 8 to make these new clues easier to follow)

> **1** might have killed **2**
>  **2** is said to have killed **4**
>  **3** is killed by **1** or **7** or hell or heaven
>  **4** is killed by **1** or **3** or most likely **2**
>  **5** probably died first
>  **6** did not kill anyone
>  **7** killed four but not **1**
>  **8** stayed away until the killing was all done.
>  If all of us are dead, who killed **7** and **1**?

**Hint #2** (I personally think this one is a dead giveaway but oh well :P )

> To prostrate oneself, oh joyous man -

**Hint #3** (Dead giveaway, I'd suggest not looking at this one unless you've tried solving with just the others)

> Hint #2 is a charade for the author's name, First and Family names separated by the comma.

Comment: "me and my children" I name you.

Comment: *facepalm*   nope, this isn't a 'lateral-thinking' type of riddle. :P

Comment: darn! Are you married, _per chance_? $_\text{(and do you have eight kids? just wonderin'...)}$

Comment: Is the name of your fifth an anagram of "his eels"? (Also, this riddle has just inspired me to write a new one!)

Comment: Nope I'm afraid not. And we really ought to stop inspiring ourselves to make more riddles and start solving the ones we've already made. I'm still trying to figure out your 7 or 8 one. >_<     but cheers :)

Comment: @Spacemonkey Is it JKR and 8 movies on HP?

Comment: If 2 killed 4, how come 4 was killed by 1 or 3 or most likely 7???

Comment: Call me weird, but some of it reminds me of the Hunger Games...

Comment: There was a ninth child, but... 7 8 9! trololol.

Comment: @rand al'thor  because Friday was a long day >_< I meant 1, 3 or most likely 2.   edited.  Thanks for the catch    --- either way, the hint is mostly to cue you in to the fact they are all killing each other?

Comment: @AJL I had exactly the same thought, but if there's only 8 of them and not 12 or 24...

Comment: Will post another hint tomorrow, its somewhat late.

Comment: Is the "last" in the final line meant to be another child, separate from 7, or the same one?

Comment: It's an eight child

Comment: Were there any girls among the children? According to my guess - yes, there must be 2 girls in the company.

Comment: I'm not sure about 2...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> The King/81st Lord of Stormend

From

> Stardust, by Neil Gaiman

Note: I am not familiar with the story having not read the book or seen the film, I worked it out based on Hints 2 and 3

> To prostrate oneself is to 'kneel' and a joyous man might be said to be a 'gay man'.

The rest I worked out via Google, Wikipedia and the work-in-question's own wiki (which is not one of the better ones I've seen).

Your first is

> Primus. I can't find reference to the knife in the riddle, but 1 might have killed 2 refers to Secondus being killed by Primus in the book (but by Septus in the film), according to the Stardust Wiki.

Your second is

> Secondus. His fall was far from bright when he died after falling/being pushed from a window. 2 is said to have killed 4, and quote the Stardust Wiki: "**Quartus, who Secundus had killed some years ago**"

Your third is

> Tertius. In the book he kept undesirable company and died "during a liason with a prostitute". In the film he drank too much wine, which was poisoned.

Your fourth is

> Quartus. He was abandoned and frozen in time when he froze to death having been locked in a cold store.

Your fifth is

> Quintus. He was killed by poisoned eels in the book, and by an axe to the head in the film.

Your sixth is

> Sextus. He was 'cooked' in a fire started by Septimus.

Your seventh is

> Septimus. Can't find reference in the Wiki about the bath, but it does have a still image from the film in which Septimus is in a bathtub. He killed four (in the book) or five (in the film) of his brothers, but Primus wasn't one of them.

Your eighth is

> Una. She might have been first (Una means 'one') but she was surely there last (she was the last survivor of the eight children).

Comment: Good job! I had a vague thought about that a few days ago but I had forgotten it contained details of how each of them died (some of them are already dead from the outset), so I dismissed the idea.

Comment: The witches kill both Primus and Septimus (the later by drowning him by voodoo)   Goodjob! I thought the riddle would be a lot easier (especially if you've seen the movie or read the book)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's:

> The days of the week: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday.

Because:

> While my last might have been first, but surely was there last: Monday or Sunday both could be the first day

Comment: But why would the 'week' (had to name the person speaking too remember, - I'm guessing that's what you meant)  not love it's days? Or any of the other clues safe the last...

Comment: Interestingly enough, the days of the week are named for greek/roman gods and planets.

Comment: Also if I've read the question correctly there are 8 children?

Comment: @starsplusplus it's wrong.

Comment: @ADG What is wrong?

Comment: @starsplusplus my answer according to OP

Comment: @Greg: You mean norse gods and stuff orbiting in the universe? Well, in dutch anyway. Tuesdays = Dinsdag : Odin's day. Wednesday = Woensdag = Wodan's day, Thursday = Donderdag = Donar's day.  (or in english Thur's day = Thor's day). Friday = Vrijdag = Frija's day. That does leave saturn, sun and moon for the other days. The whole roman good thing is months (march = Mars, june = Juno, may : Maia, January = Janus.

Comment: @TimCouwelier, I was just implying it more in that they are associated with planets and gods, greek/roman gods being the first listed here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_the_days_of_the_week , where in greek/roman mythology they have associated planets, and also have associated names (e.g. Sunday is associated with Sol/Helios, god of the sun). I'm sure there is also a basis in norse gods as well.

Comment: @Greg Sure there is, latin-based languages use that system, germanic languages use the  norse gods, etc etc. Just stating that english (which I assume is the general language here) fits into the 'germanic' system, thus Norse Gods.

Answer (score 1):

To clear up some of the things from @elf337's answer (I would put these spoilers in a comment but I don't think it's possible?)

First

> Primus has his throat cut by the witch-queen in the book

Seventh

> Septimus was also killed by the witch-queen in the book. Don't know about the bath - a bath does feature in the book but not in relation to Septimus I think. I haven't seen the film.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't go well with the hints but i thought it was funny so my answer is:

> GGR Martin and characters from aSoIaF

My first might have impressed if not for a knife.

> Khal Drogo, impressive man, but died because of a knife

My second's fall was far from bright.

> Bran Stark who fell from the tower

My third kept undesirable company or drank too much wine,

> Definitively Robert Baratheon

While my fourth was abandoned, frozen in time.

> The white walkers. It's freezing in the north and almost everybody forgot about them

My fifth liked his eels chopped and axed,

> Ramsey Bolton who chopped the "eel" from Theon

And my sixth preferred cooked, if anyone asked.

> The dragons, who burn (cook) everything

My seventh could not stand the sight of a bath,

> Maybe Osha or any wildings

While my last might have been first, but surely was there last.

> The first men who are the original human inhabitants of Westeros but there were others mythical creatures here before

Comment: Not the answer but thanks for sharing it anyway :)  I'm curious as to who the speaker would be following your answer